# Is there any to get all key and values of $scope in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my code to get all keys values I have used $scope.

```
$scope.Signup={};
$scope.Message='';
$scope.SubmitPhysicianSignup = function()
{       
    var url = site_url + 'webservices/physician_signup';
    //console.log(url);
    var physicianData = {
        "user_name_title" : $scope.user_name_title,
        "physician_first_name" : $scope.physician_first_name,
        "physician_last_name" : $scope.physician_last_name,
        "email_address" : $scope.email_address,
        "conf_email_address" : $scope.conf_email_address,
        "password" : $scope.password,
        "confpassword" : $scope.confpassword, 
        "physician_gender" : $scope.physician_gender,
        "physician_dob_date" : $scope.physician_dob_date,
        "physician_dob_month" : $scope.physician_dob_month,
        "physician_dob_year" : $scope.physician_dob_year,
        "physician_profession" : $scope.physician_profession,
        "medical_school" : $scope.medical_school,
        "traning_year" : $scope.traning_year, 
        "medical_specialty" : $scope.medical_specialty,
        "physician_minc" : $scope.physician_minc,
        "physician_country" : $scope.physician_country,
        "physician_state" : $scope.physician_state,
        "physician_city" : $scope.physician_city,
        "physician_address" : $scope.physician_address,
        "physician_postal_code" : $scope.physician_postal_code, 
        "physician_phone_number" : $scope.physician_phone_number,
        "physician_default_msg" : $scope.physician_default_msg,
        "opt_number" : $scope.opt_number,
    };
}
```

**I want to know is there any way to reduce usage of $scope and get all key and values of $scope**

Comment: Can't you not just loop over the $scope object? `for (var propName in $scope) { console.log(propName); }`

Comment: @TryingToImprove ^ needs own property check... Especially in an angular scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your data I assume that this data would be taken from form, you can get all the keys and values by ng-init a json object to be a ng-modal. Lets say ng-init="x={}" This will make you an object. Then you will have all your input elements as the keys. ng-modal="user_name_title" would become ng-modal="x['user_name_title']" and so on.. ultimately at the end while submitting you may just pass the variable x as the parameter to controller function and can use it your way... You may check that as console.log(x) in your controller after it is loaded.

And kindly let me know if I have assumed wrong.

-----------------Updated Answer -------------------------

While submitting I again assume according to the best practices, you will have to send the http request from the factory or service and not from the controller. Lets assume that you have made a factory named demoFactory and your submit form function in factory becomes demoFactory.doSubmit(x). The doSubmit() will hold the $http.post("url",x), where x is the object that you passed from view to controller to factory to the server.. and at the server side you can easily read the json.

Comment: your logic seems to be correct, you have created an array on form and fetch that array while submitting.

Comment: I updated the answer for you @Anandjain. Have a look.

Comment: Don't worry it works well. I have been doing that all the time. It is a good approach to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to simply loop through  **$scope** object with for loop.

Code below would list all own properties of **$scope** object:

```
for (var key in $scope){
  if ($scope.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log($scope[key])
}
```

Comment: Correcting my old comment, it gives the result only of fills value what about the fields that are empty.

Comment: if  you have list of non default params add checking whether  key is in that list.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop on `$scope` directly, but you have to filter angular values. They all starts with `$` or `$$`.

```
for (var key in $scope){
  if (key.charAt(0) != '$' && $scope.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log($scope[key])
  }
}
```